# How to make a keyboard layout permanent

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm currently working on a Ubuntu machine that has been set up by a user using a German keyboard layout. I prefer another one and changed it using the "Keyboard" dialog (I even deleted the old one).

However after each reboot those changes are gone. The German layout has reappeared and is (again) the default one.

How can I make those changes permanent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you clicked System->Preferences->Keyboard->Layouts->Apply System-Wide?

I seem to remember you may need to switch layout on the login screen one more time after that before it sticks.

Comment: Any particular design reason behind this "workflow"?

Comment: I would speculate that the ‘previous selection’ is always remembered and used by default, even going so far as to add it to the menu if it had been removed from the explicit list of layouts.

Comment: Bobince is right, AFAIK. You need to switch layout on the login screen for it to stick.

Comment: nice observation! that behaviour is...strange..to put it nicely. The relevant bug is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/546785 (status fixed is somewhat confusing, though)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this worked for me on my Mint 17.2 installation
I was getting a backslash for hash key etc
The standard default layout was set for English (US)
and I removed this and added just ENGLISH